# How retrieve intent slot value, drive me crazy

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I simply want to retrieve to slot value on code, I wanna try to do a simple skill who respond in different ways according to day sopeak from users.

This is my sample code, I'm trying in blank project for don't have other issue.

The intent is "HelloWorldIntent" the slot is "day"

JSON:

```html
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "try",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "HelloWorldIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "day",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DayOfWeek"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "good {day}",
                        "hello",
                        "how are you",
                        "say hi world",
                        "say hi",
                        "hi",
                        "say hello world",
                        "say hello"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

The index.js is:

```js
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        var app = this.event.request.intent.slots.day.value;
        const speechText = app;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

When I ask good Monday (or any other day) the result is Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said. Please try again.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you also using the skill invocation name, such as "Alexa, ask try to good Monday"?
Did you build the interaction model?
Does it work with the written tests in the Alexa Developer console?

Comment: Yes I call "Alexa start try" and then I call "good Monday" and the result is "Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said"

Comment: Yes I build the interaction model, and deploy the code, and no it does't work neither in Alexa Developer Console.

Comment: weird, I would suggest to remove every other utterance and just leave a couple of similar utterances that are not "common". Alexa might recognize "good Monday" as a phrase a user will say normally, thus not connecting it to your utterance. Try something like "what will I wear {day}"

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

`var app = this.event.request.intent.slots.day.value;`

That looks like code for the v1 of the SDK.

It looks like you're actually using v2 - if you have the most recent version, to get a slot value you can do this:

```
// Require the SDK at the top of your file

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
```

```
// Then in your handle function where you want the slot value

handle (handlerInput) {
  const { requestEnvelope } = handlerInput;

  const speechText = Alexa.getSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'day');

  return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speechText).getResponse();
}
```

Alternatively, you could also get it like this:

```
const speechText = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots['day'].value
```

[Request Envelope Utils - ASK SDK v2](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ASK-SDK-Utilities.html#requestenvelopeutils)